# Path expected for join error

Tags: hibernate, createquery

I'm attempting to execute the following query and I get the above error. 
Any ideas?

```
session.CreateQuery("SELECT SUM(NumberHead) AS numberhead " +
                     "FROM Purchase "
                     +"INNER JOIN Lot " 
                     + "ON Purchase.FeedLot = Lot.Id "
                     + "WHERE Purchase.CohortState = 0").List();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT SUM(purchase.NumberHead) AS numberhead FROM Purchase purchase INNER JOIN Lot lot ON purchase.FeedLot = lot.Id WHERE purchase.CohortState = 0
```

Comment: how do entity class look like? any explicit relationship between Purchase and Lot? if there is OneToOne or OneToMany between entities, If there is, then no need to put **Purchase.FeedLot = Lot.Id** in query. And the query would look like this **SELECT SUM(purchase.NumberHead) AS numberhead FROM Purchase purchase INNER JOIN purchase.FeedLot WHERE purchase.CohortState = 0**

Comment: A lot can have many purchases, a purchase can only belong to one lot

Comment: have you tried this one **SELECT SUM(purchase.NumberHead) AS numberhead FROM Purchase purchase INNER JOIN purchase.FeedLot  WHERE purchase.CohortState = 0**